# Can't insert Point in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, spatial-query

I wrote next Insert function:

```
INSERT INTO test(datetime, points) VALUES('2014-12-29 12:09:35', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(6370526.653 11224882.055)', 3395));
```

When I run it, I am getting error, that function "ST_GeomFromText not found". I can't understand why am getting this error. PostGIS is installed, filed with Point type created.

I tried a lot of other variants like: ST_POINT (or just Points without ST_GeomFromText, but it did not help).

Comment: Did you do `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` to install PostGIS?

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT` statement looks correct.

If Postgres can't find the function, and you are certain you did install PostGis in the same database, you probably installed it into a **schema** that's not listed in your [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777). Either fix your installation or adapt your `search_path` setting.